# take input until input positive number

Tags: java

Take two integers p & q ... Sum should be printed of p to next q numbers including p .. if q <= 0 , then it will take the value of q again ...

Input :::: 3 2
Output :::: 7 (p=3 & q = 2 ..... So from 3 to next 2 numbers are 3 & 4 as it will be included in the sum ... Now we will have to print the sum of 3+4 and that's 7 )

Input ::: 4 -1 1
Output :::. 4 ( as the next number is 4 )

That means we have to start counting from the taken integer ....

Solve it and drop the solution here ......

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ahmed {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int p=sc.nextInt();
      int q=sc.nextInt();
      int sum=0;
      if(q>=0){
      for(int i=1; i<=q ;i++) {
        sum=p+sum;
        p++;
       }
      }
      else{
        q=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=1; i<=q ;i++) {
        sum=p+sum;
        p++;
       }
      }
      System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

if I take input 4 -1 -1 there is a error. Loop will continue until I take q input a positive number or 0;

Correct input 4 -1 -1 2 output 9.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when we have a loop and we dont know how many times it will repeat, we can use `while`.

Create a function like this:

```
private int readPositiveInt(Scanner sc){
    int i = -1
    while (i <= 0) {
        i = sc.nextInt();
    }
    return i;
}
```

Then, you replace this line of code `int q=sc.nextInt();` by this:

```
int q = readPositiveInt(sc);
```

Finally, once q will be positive for sure, you can remove these lines:

```
else{
    q=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=1; i<=q ;i++) {
    sum=p+sum;
    p++;
   }
  }
```